# Runge Kutta plot graphic

Tags: matlab, graph, octave

i have this code in octave for the runge kutta of the 4th order method but i cant create a graph

```
dy=@(x,y)-x^2+2*y;
f=@(x)exp(x^2/2);

a=0;
b=2;
y=1;
y0=1;
m=20;
h=(b-a)/m;
k=0;


fprintf('k \t x \t\t y (RK4) \t k1 \t\t k2 \t\t k3 \t\t k4 \n')
fprintf('%d \t %f \t %f \t\n', k,a,y);
for x=a:h:b-h
  k1=dy(x,y)*h;
  k2=dy((x+h)/2,(y+k1)/2)*h;
  k3=dy((x+h)/2,(y+k2)/2)*h;
  k4=dy((x+h)/2,(y+k3)/2)*h;
  k=k+1;
  y=y+dy(x,y)*h;
  x=x+h;
  fprintf('%d \t %f \t %f \t %f \t %f \t %f \t %f \t  \n', k,x,y,k1,k2,k3,k4);
end

fprintf('yn= %f \n',RK4("fedo",a,b,y0,m));
fprintf('Eroarea comisa este de ordinul lui %d \n',h^2);
```

and i need to create a graph but i dont know what to plot
help?

Comment: if you don't know what to plot, how can we even imagine what you want to plot?

Comment: @femaletitan, your 2nd to last line is referencing a RK4 function that is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

First, there is an undefined `RK4` function in your fprintf statements that doesn't allow us to see the full printed output you desired, but your other code runs, and it looks like the last line is just printing the error estimate.  Let's look at the output that does display:

```
k        x               y (RK4)         k1              k2              k3              k4
0        0.000000        1.000000
1        0.100000        1.200000        0.200000        0.119750        0.111725        0.110923
2        0.200000        1.439000        0.239000        0.142900        0.133290        0.132329
3        0.300000        1.722800        0.283800        0.170030        0.158653        0.157515
4        0.400000        2.058360        0.335560        0.201836        0.188464        0.187126
5        0.500000        2.454032        0.395672        0.239153        0.223501        0.221936
6        0.600000        2.919838        0.465806        0.282984        0.264702        0.262873
7        0.700000        3.467806        0.547968        0.334531        0.313187        0.311053
8        0.800000        4.112367        0.644561        0.395237        0.370304        0.367811
9        0.900000        4.870841        0.758473        0.466834        0.437670        0.434754
10       1.000000        5.764009        0.893168        0.551401        0.517224        0.513806
11       1.100000        6.816811        1.052802        0.651431        0.611294        0.607280
12       1.200000        8.059173        1.242362        0.769917        0.722673        0.717948
13       1.300000        9.527007        1.467835        0.910451        0.854712        0.849139
14       1.400000        11.263409       1.736401        1.077341        1.011435        1.004844
15       1.500000        13.320091       2.056682        1.275759        1.197667        1.189858
16       1.600000        15.759109       2.439018        1.511911        1.419200        1.409929
17       1.700000        18.654931       2.895822        1.793243        1.682985        1.671959
18       1.800000        22.096917       3.441986        2.128692        1.997362        1.984229
19       1.900000        26.192300       4.095383        2.528980        2.372340        2.356676
20       2.000000        31.069760       4.877460        3.006976        2.819928        2.801223
```

There is a lot here that you could plot.  But there's a small problem here, which is that all of that data is not saved in any variables. It's just printed to the screen and then overwritten on the next iteration of your RK loop. For example, after the program runs your workspace contains the following variables:

```
>> whos
Variables visible from the current scope:

variables in scope: top scope

   Attr Name        Size                     Bytes  Class
   ==== ====        ====                     =====  =====
        a           1x1                          8  double
        b           1x1                          8  double
        dy          1x1                          0  function_handle
        f           1x1                          0  function_handle
        h           1x1                          8  double
        k           1x1                          8  double
        k1          1x1                          8  double
        k2          1x1                          8  double
        k3          1x1                          8  double
        k4          1x1                          8  double
        m           1x1                          8  double
        x           1x1                          8  double
        y           1x1                          8  double
        y0          1x1                          8  double

>> k1
k1 = 4.8775
```

where all of the variables only retain the last value, `k1` shown as an example.

If you want to plot the information, you need to retain the information to plot. if I manually copied/pasted your data into the terminal to define a data variable (ignoring the first partial line):

```
>> data = [1        0.100000        1.200000        0.200000        0.119750        0.111725        0.110923
2        0.200000        1.439000        0.239000        0.142900        0.133290        0.132329
3        0.300000        1.722800        0.283800        0.170030        0.158653        0.157515
4        0.400000        2.058360        0.335560        0.201836        0.188464        0.187126
5        0.500000        2.454032        0.395672        0.239153        0.223501        0.221936
6        0.600000        2.919838        0.465806        0.282984        0.264702        0.262873
7        0.700000        3.467806        0.547968        0.334531        0.313187        0.311053
8        0.800000        4.112367        0.644561        0.395237        0.370304        0.367811
9        0.900000        4.870841        0.758473        0.466834        0.437670        0.434754
10       1.000000        5.764009        0.893168        0.551401        0.517224        0.513806
11       1.100000        6.816811        1.052802        0.651431        0.611294        0.607280
12       1.200000        8.059173        1.242362        0.769917        0.722673        0.717948
13       1.300000        9.527007        1.467835        0.910451        0.854712        0.849139
14       1.400000        11.263409       1.736401        1.077341        1.011435        1.004844
15       1.500000        13.320091       2.056682        1.275759        1.197667        1.189858
16       1.600000        15.759109       2.439018        1.511911        1.419200        1.409929
17       1.700000        18.654931       2.895822        1.793243        1.682985        1.671959
18       1.800000        22.096917       3.441986        2.128692        1.997362        1.984229
19       1.900000        26.192300       4.095383        2.528980        2.372340        2.356676
20       2.000000        31.069760       4.877460        3.006976        2.819928        2.801223];
```

Then I can plot all sorts of things, like `y` vs `k`, or `y` vs `x`, etc:

plot (data(:,1), data(:,3)); title ("y vs k");
figure
plot (data(:,2), data(:,3)); title ("y vs x");

[image: sample data plots]

So the big question is how to retain your data so you aren't reliant on copy/paste.

Octave and Matlab variables are arrays.  In your case, the variables you store your data in are single element, 1x1 arrays, and you overwrite them every iteration.  An alternative approach is to use a vector for each variable (just as your printed output appears), and to store values from each iteration in a different vector location, indexed by `k`.

I notice that some of your variables you print are actually not the variables you use for each step.  E.g., for `k = 1`, you print `x = 0.1` but all of those values are calculated with `k= 0` and `x = 0`. You then increment `x` and `k` right before printing.  So some of those details might need to be tweaked to get what you want to match with what follows:

Since you're using `x` to define your steps, you probably want to expand that to an array first:

```
>> x=[a:h:b-h];

>> x'

x =

        0
   0.1000
   0.2000
   0.3000
   0.4000
   0.5000
   0.6000
   0.7000
   0.8000
   0.9000
   1.0000
   1.1000
   1.2000
   1.3000
   1.4000
   1.5000
   1.6000
   1.7000
   1.8000
   1.9000
```

(Note the vector is normally a row vector, I used a `'` (transpose operator) to makes it display as a column vector here. I do the same at the end for storing results.)

The following rewritten RK loop produces an output much like your previous output:

```
x=[a:h:b];

for k = 1:length(x)-1
  k1(k+1) = dy(x(k),y(k))*h;
  k2(k+1) = dy((x(k)+h)/2,(y(k)+k1(k+1))/2)*h;
  k3(k+1) = dy((x(k)+h)/2,(y(k)+k2(k+1))/2)*h;
  k4(k+1) = dy((x(k)+h)/2,(y(k)+k3(k+1))/2)*h;
  y(k+1) = y(k) + dy(x(k),y(k))*h;
end


data = [x',y',k1',k2',k3',k4']

data =

         0    1.0000         0         0         0         0
    0.1000    1.2000    0.2000    0.1198    0.1117    0.1109
    0.2000    1.4390    0.2390    0.1429    0.1333    0.1323
    0.3000    1.7228    0.2838    0.1700    0.1587    0.1575
    0.4000    2.0584    0.3356    0.2018    0.1885    0.1871
    0.5000    2.4540    0.3957    0.2392    0.2235    0.2219
    0.6000    2.9198    0.4658    0.2830    0.2647    0.2629
    0.7000    3.4678    0.5480    0.3345    0.3132    0.3111
    0.8000    4.1124    0.6446    0.3952    0.3703    0.3678
    0.9000    4.8708    0.7585    0.4668    0.4377    0.4348
    1.0000    5.7640    0.8932    0.5514    0.5172    0.5138
    1.1000    6.8168    1.0528    0.6514    0.6113    0.6073
    1.2000    8.0592    1.2424    0.7699    0.7227    0.7179
    1.3000    9.5270    1.4678    0.9105    0.8547    0.8491
    1.4000   11.2634    1.7364    1.0773    1.0114    1.0048
    1.5000   13.3201    2.0567    1.2758    1.1977    1.1899
    1.6000   15.7591    2.4390    1.5119    1.4192    1.4099
    1.7000   18.6549    2.8958    1.7932    1.6830    1.6720
    1.8000   22.0969    3.4420    2.1287    1.9974    1.9842
    1.9000   26.1923    4.0954    2.5290    2.3723    2.3567
    2.0000   31.0698    4.8775    3.0070    2.8199    2.8012
```

(Also note octave and matlab start indexing at 1 not zero, hence all the `k+1's`)

Now that all of the data is stored and retained in the individual variable vectors or in the data array, you can make any plots you want. Recommend you check out [the Octave manual section on plotting](https://octave.org/doc/latest/Two_002dDimensional-Plots.html).